# Which Nvidia driver should I use for a NVS315 + NVS290 combo?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.10

I have a relatively old workstation with two cards inside (only one is used for display). The system runs 16.10.

I've tried using the recommended driver for the NVS315 (I will update this question with more details later), but it leads to a blank screen.

Nouveau works fine, but Adobe Flash doesn't seem to like it too much, and it seems to cause some redrawing issues in Blender 3D.

Comment: Merry Christmas Roland and a happy new year. Which specific driver did you test?

Comment: Merry New Christmas and Happy Year to you too ;P

I tried 304.132 and 340.98 (IIRC)